# Setting default values in decimal model/reset textboxes back to blank instead of 0 for mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have two issues that revolve around decimal text boxes and submitting the correct value to a report. This is MVC 3 C# with Razor.

My users want to run a report for a specific price range, Start Price Range and End Price Range.  Both are text boxes with decimal datatype defined in the model.  They are also optional as there are some other parameters the user can select from but I am having trouble with the decimal type specifically.  Both text boxes default to 0 when the view loads and also when reset via clear button.  I need this to have a default value of blank when the view loads and also when reset.  I have set the following in the view and it works just fine to show blank fields.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PriceRangeStart, new { @Value = (Model.PriceRangeStart > 0 ? Model.PriceRangeStart : 0) })
```

However, The only problem is that it is still looking for a value when I try to run the report and gives the user "Parameter is required" when it is not required to run the report.  Is there a way to also pass a null value or even a 0 behind the scenes?

I have googled incessantly and tried several default value options in the model and nothing is working at all.  I tried placeholders in the view.  Ive tried HiddenFor fields. I tried  default values in the like the following:

```
public SellerActivityReport()
{
  decimal? a = null;
  PriceRangeStart = a.GetValueOrDefault(0m);
  PriceRangeEnd = a.GetValueOrDefault(0m);
}
```

I really don't want to have to go back and change all of these to accept strings only if I dont have to! Just completely stuck if this is even possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make the `PriceRangeStart` property on your view model a nullable decimal:

```
public decimal? PriceRangeStart { get; set; }
```

and then inside the view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.PriceRangeStart)
```

Now if there's no value (empty string) the property will have a null value.